# Laravel 5.4 Webpack Mix - merge SCSS and CSS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

Is there any way to merge SCSS and CSS?

Currently I do it as follows but it doesn't work. The code below supposed to compile scss into a temp directory and then merge it with the plain css.

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', '../resources/assets/tmp_compilation_files/scss-assets.css').styles([ 'resources/assets/tmp_compilation_files/scss-assets.css', 'node_modules/isteven-angular-multiselect/isteven-multi-select.css' ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

but nothing. The compiled SASS is missing in the public/css/app.css file. This is so annoying, such a simple task and it's not doable. I was able to do it with elixir - compiling scss into a tmp directory (./resources/tmp) and then merging it with the css files using styles().

I also haven't found any info in the documentation about the path params - where I specify absolute paths, where relative to the public directory?

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing it.  My approach has been to, (given your file names), replace:

`mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', '../resources/assets/tmp_compilation_files/scss-assets.css').styles([ 'resources/assets/tmp_compilation_files/scss-assets.css', 'node_modules/isteven-angular-multiselect/isteven-multi-select.css' ], 'public/css/app.css');`

with:

```
mix.copy('resources/assets/tmp_compilation_files/scss-assets.css', 'resources/assets/sass/_scss-assets.scss');
mix.copy('node_modules/isteven-angular-multiselect/isteven-multi-select.css', 'resources/assets/sass/_isteven-multi-select.scss');
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Then add the following lines into app.scss:

```
@import "scss-assets";
@import "isteven-multi-select";
```

And that's it.  When you next compile your assets, (i.e. - through `npm run dev`), it should have all compiled.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't make an API for that. This css->scss renaming doesn't look good. Who cares of course, but still.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is rename the CSS file to _*Name*.scss and import it into my main SCSS file.

---

For example, if I have a vendor sheet named magnific-popup.css, I will rename it to _magnific-popup.scss, then use the CSS import clause:

```
/*Called in scss entre-point file. (e.g. app.scss)*/
@import "../vendor/magnific-popup.scss"
```

Then in Laravel Mix I have the original scss method call that combines everything:

```
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Following an `npm run dev` command, I can include the merged result by calling the mix helper method in my `<header>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```