# merge css and scss in laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

This is my code:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'resources/assets/css')
   .styles([
     'resources/assets/css/animate.min.css'
   ],'resources/assets/css/style.css')
   .combine(['resources/assets/css/style.css','resources/assets/css/app.css'], 'public/css/app.css');
```

and results:

> \js\app.js   928 kB
>
> \resources\assets\css\app.css   185 kB
>
> \resources\assets\css\style.css  52.8 kB
>
> \css\all.css  52.8 kB

You can see,It can merge app.css with style.css. output is only style.css as all.css

what is wrong?

Comment: Old question, but if anyone else ends up here like I did - Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051188/laravel-5-4-wbpack-mix-merge-scss-and-css (solution is the same for Laravel 5.4 and up)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 Webpack Mix - merge SCSS and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051188/laravel-5-4-webpack-mix-merge-scss-and-css)